# Can you move (or duplicate) the "special" .Net folders (App_*) in a subdirectory?

Tags: themes, app-code, app-themes

It is possible to have extra .Net "special" folders (App_Code, App_Themes, etc.) inside of a subdirectory, rather than in the root?

I am integrating with a CMS that dumps an enormous amount of stuff in the root.  I would like to keep all my stuff in a single subfolder, as this will greatly ease my SVN and deployment burden.  As it sits, I have to pick through all the stuff to figure out what's mine and what's theirs, selectively committing and ignoring -- it takes about an hour.

I can sure put all my Web forms in a folder.  But I have classes in the App_Code and images and stylesheets in App_Themes that I need to deal with.

So, is there anyway to have an *additional* App_Code and App_Themes in a subdirectory, or are these limited to the root only?

(And, yes, I know about creating an Appication, but this won't work.  I need to run in the same context as everything in the root of the site, so it's not really a separate, conceptual application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only have one App_Code folder per ASP.NET application.